# Infinite scroll in QueueAnim component

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to make a list of notification with enter and exit animations and infinite scroll.

I am using a custom intersection observer hook in order to trigger the infinite scroll and `rc-queue-anim` from `ant-motion` library for the animation.

The infinite scrolling is working without any problems if I don't use the `rc-queue-anim` wrapper. But as soon as I do, the infinite scroll no longer triggers.

Here is the infinite scroll working example:

```
const NotificationList: React.FC<Props> = ( props: Props ) => {

  const { items, isLoading, isHistory, isError, loadMore, hasNext } = props;

  const sentryRef = useInfiniteScroll( {
    hasNextPage: hasNext,
    loadMore,
    isLoading,
    isDisabled: !!isError
  } );

  const notifications = useMemo( () => {
    if ( isLoading && hasNext ) return new Array( 5 ).fill( null ).map( ( _, index ) => <Notification status={ NotificationStatus.unread } type={ 'info' } title='' description='' actions={ [] } _id={ v4() } from='' loading={ isLoading } subject={ '' } key={ index } isHistory={ isHistory } /> );
    return items.map( ( notification, index ) =>
      <Notification
        { ...notification }
        ref={ index === items.length - 1 ? sentryRef : null }
        loading={ isLoading }
        isHistory={ isHistory }
        key={ notification._id }
      />
    );
  }, [ items, isLoading, hasNext ] );

  if ( isError ) return (
    <Result
      status="error"
      title="Network error"
      subTitle="Something went wrong! Please try again later."
    />
  );

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Content>
        { notifications }
      </Content>
    </Layout >
  );

};

};
```

And here with the animations, but the infinite scroll no longer works:

```
const NotificationList: React.FC<Props> = ( props: Props ) => {

  const { items, isLoading, isHistory, isError, loadMore, hasNext } = props;

  const sentryRef = useInfiniteScroll( {
    hasNextPage: hasNext,
    loadMore,
    isLoading,
    isDisabled: !!isError
  } );

  const notifications = useMemo( () => {
    if ( isLoading && hasNext ) return new Array( 5 ).fill( null ).map( ( _, index ) => <Notification status={ NotificationStatus.unread } type={ 'info' } title='' description='' actions={ [] } _id={ v4() } from='' loading={ isLoading } subject={ '' } key={ index } isHistory={ isHistory } /> );
    return items.map( ( notification, index ) =>
      <Notification
        { ...notification }
        ref={ index === items.length - 1 ? sentryRef : null }
        loading={ isLoading }
        isHistory={ isHistory }
        key={ notification._id }
      />
    );
  }, [ items, isLoading, hasNext ] );

  if ( isError ) return (
    <Result
      status="error"
      title="Network error"
      subTitle="Something went wrong! Please try again later."
    />
  );

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Content>
        <QueueAnim type={ [ 'right', 'left' ] } leaveReverse key="notification-list">
          { notifications }
        </QueueAnim>
      </Content>
    </Layout >
  );

};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, here is the `useInfiniteScroll` hook. Is streight forward:

```
import { useCallback, useRef } from "react";

interface Props {
  loadMore: () => void;
  hasNextPage?: boolean;
  isDisabled?: boolean;
  isLoading?: boolean;
}

export const useInfiniteScroll = ( props: Props ) => {
  const { isLoading, loadMore: next, hasNextPage, isDisabled } = props;
  const intObserver = useRef<IntersectionObserver>();
  const itemRef = useCallback( ( item: HTMLElement ) => {
    if ( isLoading || isDisabled ) return;

    if ( intObserver.current ) intObserver.current.disconnect();

    intObserver.current = new IntersectionObserver( items => {
      if ( items[ 0 ].isIntersecting && hasNextPage ) {
        console.log( "havava" );
        next();
      }
    } );
    if ( item ) intObserver.current.observe( item );
  }, [ hasNextPage, isLoading ] );

  return itemRef;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the fact that I am using the ref property for the `sentryRef`. The `QueueAnim` component is replacing the ref so the `sentryRef` is later on `null`. In order to make it work, I had to wrap the `Notification` component in a div so that the `QueueAnim` component uses the `div` to place the ref.

```
const notifications = useMemo( () => {
    if ( isLoading && hasNext ) return new Array( 5 ).fill( null ).map( ( _, index ) => <Notification status={ NotificationStatus.unread } type={ 'info' } title='' description='' actions={ [] } _id={ v4() } from='' loading={ isLoading } subject={ '' } key={ index } isHistory={ isHistory } /> );
    return items.map( ( notification, index ) =>
    <div>
      <Notification
        { ...notification }
        ref={ index === items.length - 1 ? sentryRef : null }
        loading={ isLoading }
        isHistory={ isHistory }
        key={ notification._id }
      />
    </div>
    );
  }, [ items, isLoading, hasNext ] );
```